# Username Token in block doesn't work

Tags: tokens

I'm  using Drupal 7 and installed the [Token filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module.

I want to display a welcome message in block; I used `<h2>Welcome [user:name]! </h2>` as token, but the token is not recognized.

Why isn't the token recognized? Which token should I use?

Comment: detail blog:http://goo.gl/77zEds

Answer (score 2):

Try this token instead:

```
[current-user:name]
```

Answer (score -1):

This `[current-user:name]` token works in block title.